# VIM: How to replace each instance of a string with a different value

Tags: regex, vim, text, text-editor

Let's say I have some code:

```
divide(int x) {
int a = 0;
a += x;
}

subtract(int x) {
int b = 0;
b += x;
}

multiply(int x) {
int c = 0;
c += x;
}
```

I'm using VIM and I'd like to be able to search and replace each instance of += with `{'/=', '-=', '*='}` in that order, using the vim command line.
I'd like to use `:%s/+=/...`, but I'm not sure how.

I also thought about using python in vim like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501585/how-can-you-use-python-in-vim), but I would prefer a simpler solution entirely in VIM, if possible.

Comment: Related post: [In Vim how can I search and replace every other match?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13763880/438329)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of your `+=` occur on different lines:

```
:let c=0 | g/\m+=/ s!\m+=!\=['/=', '-=', '*='][c%3]! | let c+=1
```

If there might be more than one `+=` on the same line:

```
:fu! Cycle() | let c+=1 | return ['/=', '-=', '*='][c%3] | endf
:let c=-1 | %s/\m+=/\=Cycle()/g
```

References:

- `:h :global`
- `:h s/\=`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer! Could you explain a bit in detail about why this works?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter variant of @SatoKatsura's answer. It first defines a List of replacements, then uses a `:help sub-replace-expression` to remove the first element of the list.

```
:let replacements = ['/=', '-=', '*='] | %s#+=#\=remove(replacements, 0)#
```

If there are more than 3 replacements, and you want repeating of the replacements, use this:

```
:let replacements = ['/=', '-=', '*='] | %s#+=#\=add(replacements, remove(replacements, 0))[-1]#
```

Comment: Ok, so then why does this work exactly? I understand everything up to the first # after %s.

Comment: `remove()` returns the element that is removed from the pre-populated list. So, each substitution removes (and uses) one element from the list. The second variant prevents that the list gets empty by re-adding each element again.